# como mostrar datos de una api json en html?

Tags: javascript, html, json, api

hola necesito mostrar elementos que me muestra la api en formato json en mi documento html,
mi api me da lo siguiente:
[image: consola]

el codigo js es el siguiente :

```
const url='http://192.168.0.79:8080/Presentacion/SirtacAlicuotaServlet'

fetch(url)
.then(response=> response.json() )
.then(data => {

    let elementos=document.getElementById('elemento')
    elementos.innerHTML =  `
    <td>${data.index}</td>
    <td>${data.letra}</td>
    <td>${data.alicuota}</td>
    <td>${data.periodo}</td>
    <td>${data.estado}</td>
    `;
    console.table(data)
})
.catch(err=>console.log(err))
```

en el html es asi:

```
 <H1 align="left"><strong> Alicuotas</strong></H1>

        
        <table align="center" border="1">
          <tr>
          <td id="index">index</td>
          <td id="letra">letra</td>
          <td id="alicuota">alicuota</td>
          <td id="periodo">periodo</td>
          <td id="estado">estado</td>
          </tr>
          </table>
          <div align="center" id="elemento"></div>
```

me da undefined ,como lo soluciono?

Comment: Tendrías que poner un ejemplo mínimo de como es `data`, seguramente sea un array que tienes que recorrer.

Comment: la data es lo que sale en la imagen ,es un array de 28 elementos, contiene un index, una letra, una alicuota ,periodo y estado

Comment: Has probado hacer uso de ``fetch(url).then(function(response) {
  //La variable response tiene datos, recoge los datos por aqui.
});``. De todas formas usa un depurador en el data para asegurar.

Comment: tambien lo hice con fetch pero es el mismo problema, no me muestra los datos en el html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este código debe estar dentro de `.then`, basicamente se recorre `data` con `forEach`, cada iteración de esas es una fila, y luego se recorre cada propiedad de cada elemento con `for in`, cada iteración de esas es una columna dentro de esa fila.

```js
const data = [{letra:"A",alicuota:18.5,periodo:3,estado:"A"},
{letra:"B",alicuota:18.3,periodo:5,estado:"B"}]; //<-- Es solo un ejemplo minimo

const table = document.getElementById("alicuotas");

data.forEach((e,i) => {    //< ---  recorremos data

  let tr = document.createElement("tr"); //< ---  creamos una fila
  
  let td = document.createElement("td"); //< ---  Hacemos columna index dentro de la fila
  td.classList.add("index");
  td.innerHTML = i;
  tr.appendChild(td); //< --- Agregamos la columna en la fila

  for (p in e) {  //< ---  recorremos cada propiedad de cada elemento

    let td = document.createElement("td"); //< ---  Hacemos columna dentro de la fila
    td.classList.add(p);//<-- le podemos agregar a toda la columna la misma clase
    td.innerHTML = e[p]; 

    tr.appendChild(td); //< --- Agregamos la columna en la fila

  }

  table.appendChild(tr); //< --- Agregamos la fila a la tabla

});
```

```html
<H1 align="left"><strong> Alicuotas</strong></H1>
<table align="center" border="1" id="alicuotas">
  <tr>
    <td id="index">index</td>
    <td id="letra">letra</td>
    <td id="alicuota">alicuota</td>
    <td id="periodo">periodo</td>
    <td id="estado">estado</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div align="center" id="elemento"></div>
```

Comment: yo lo ejecute y me sale igual. me da error

Comment: Cuidado que al html yo le agregue un id a la tabla `id="alicuotas"`

Comment: copie todo y me da error :  ```

Comment: Me olvidé de aclarar lo del id, pero debería funcionar sin problemas, que error dice?

Comment: vi el id ,lo agregue pero al ejecutar no me muestra los datos

Comment: lo escribi asi: fetch(url)
.then(response=> response.json() )
.then(data => {
const table = document.getElementById("alicuotas");
    
    data.forEach(e => {    //< ---  recorremos data  let tr = document.createElement("tr"); //< ---  creamos una fila
    
      for (p in e) {  //< ---  recorremos cada propiedad de cada elemento
    
        let td = document.createElement("td"); //< ---  Hacemos columna dentro de la fila
        td.classList.add(p);//<-- le podemos agregar a toda la columna la misma clase
        td.innerHTML = e[p];

Comment: tr.appendChild(td); //< --- Agregamos la columna en la fila
    
      }
    
      table.appendChild(tr); //< --- Agregamos la fila a la tabla
    
    });
})
.catch(err=>console.log(err))

Comment: y en la tabla le agregue el id

Comment: si , justo despues de .then (data => puse todo

Comment: hice un pequeño cambio porque `index` no es parte del objeto en verdad, por eso en el `console.table` figura como  `(index)`

Answer (score 0):

Si ya lo tienes asi hazlo mejor con datatable

https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html

Comment: La idea no es mala, pero deberías incluír un mínimo código de como haría eso

Comment: De hecho, deberías eliminar tu respuesta y agregarla como comentario si no puedes desarrollar mas el tema, pues puede que sea mal votada y afecte tu reputación, un saludo, si puedes desarrollarla mas, edita.